# Dynamically insert date into gridview header

Tags: asp.net, templates, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview that compares data between the current year and last year.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="st_entity_id" HeaderText="Entity ID" SortExpression="st_entity_id" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalConsentsThisYear" HeaderText="Total Consents for Year" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TotalConsentsThisYear" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalConsentsLastYear" HeaderText="Total Consents for last Year" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TotalConsentsLastYear" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalIssuedConsentsThisYear" HeaderText="Total Issued Consents for Year" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TotalIssuedConsentsThisYear" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalIssuedConsentsLastYear" HeaderText="Total Issued Consents for last Year" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TotalIssuedConsentsLastYear" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalInspectionsThisYear" HeaderText="Total Inspections for Year" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TotalInspectionsThisYear" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalInspectionsLastYear" HeaderText="Total Inspections for last Year" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TotalInspectionsLastYear" />
</Columns>
```

However, I would like the gridview to display *Total Inspections for 2014* instead of *Total Inspections for last Year*. I know that I have to use a template field to do this, but I don't know how to format it to achieve the required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how i did it for the first column of the grid view (adjust for any column you want) :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string curHeader = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text;
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = string.Format("{0} for {1}", curHeader, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year);
}
```

And the result i got:

[image]